# How to use SQLite on new Windows 8.1 Store app (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, sqlite, managed, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

So, I installed Visual Studio 2013 on my Windows 8.1 box. I want to experiment with it and created a new **Windows Store Grid App**. I want to persist data on a SQLite database, apparently the database of choice for WinRT apps.

Quickly found links to the vsix needed in order to be able to use the SDK: [SQLite download page](http://sqlite.org/download.html), and downloaded sqlite-winrt81-3080002.vsix.

Installed it, then in my project, added the reference to the newly installed SDK (right click references, add reference, navigate to Windows, select extensions and tick SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) checkbox.

Also quickly found that it won't compile on Any CPU. On Configuration Manager, selected Debug, x64 active platform, that made me able to compile the application.

Finally, while attempting to use the namespace `SQLite` I noticed VS 2013 isn't recognizing it. Attempted many things like adding reference to the .dll directly, exploring the component to see which namespaces were available (which doesn't show anything), and I'm quickly running out of ideas. Because it's kinda new thing, and with limited interest, google, the saviour, doesn't want to save me today.

So, how one would be able to use the SQLite SDK in their Visual Studio 2013 projects, targeting Windows Runtime 8.1?

[These are the contents of my csproj file](http://pastebin.com/pGHHerHq)

**UPDATE**
Stupid me, thought there was no managed land (.net) in Metro style land. Sorry for causing any confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I installed the VSIX for SQLite and noticed that it is a native DLL to be used in Windows Store 8.1 C++ apps.  It is not for managed C# projects.

The current NuGet package for SQLite from what seems to be the 'official' SQLite team is only working for .NET 4.5, if you try to install it, it will error saying it does not support .NET 4.51.

There is also the NuGet package SQLite-net, which works for .NET Windows Store apps. All you need to add is the SQLite using statement.

You will need this NuGet package as it is the managed wrapper for the SQLite, without you will not be able to properly reference the right DLL for SQLite.

Here is the link to the project information from that NuGet package.  [SQLite Runtime Support](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Here is an article on how to use SQLite with Windows Store apps in VS2012 but it should still all apply:

[SQLite and Windows Store Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx)

Comment: Appreciate the answer but what I'm looking for is indeed native windows 8.1 store app, and not .net. Would you need though a library for c++ and a different one for C#?

Comment: @JoaoMilasch But it looks like you project is C# as in the pasted csproj file.  It is still going to be a true Windows Store app but you will need the managed provider for SQLite as it is a wrapper for the C++ library.

Comment: Yes, C# can also be used for Windows RT as well as Visual Basic and C++.

Comment: Guess I missed the sqlite-net. Really appreciated =]