# Can't reference System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble to reference a System.Data.Sqlite to my project. I use visual studio 2013 and created a Windows Store Application Project I need to reference it to this DLL for sql but gives me this error. Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Well, the issue here is that your project isn't targeting the .NET Framework, it's targeting the .NET Core. You'd need to find the SQLite assembly for Windows Store applications.

Comment: http://ambilykk.com/2012/08/29/windows-8-the-project-targets-netframework-while-the-file-reference-targets-netcore/

Comment: Good find @SonerGönül.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I understand the problem now but I can't understand what steps I need to take in order for me to target .Net Framework to my app?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate question.  This question has all the required steps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672309/how-to-use-sqlite-on-new-windows-8-1-store-app-visual-studio-2013